# Immutable Array with Mutable Objects Java

Tags: java, immutability

I have a simple class "A", which is mutable.

I would like to achieve immutable list using mutable objects "A" without creating class that guarantees immutability for objects of type "A". Is this possible?

```
public class App{
    public class A{
        int a;

        public A() {}

        public A(int a) {
            super();
            this.a = a;
        }

        public int getA() {
            return a;
        }

        public void setA(int a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "A [a=" + a + "]";
        }

    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        A a = app.new A(0);
        ArrayList<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>();
        aList.add(a);
        System.out.println(aList.toString());//result is 0 as expected
        a.setA(99);
        System.out.println(aList.toString());//result is 99 as expected
        ImmutableList<A> immutableList = ImmutableList.copyOf(new ArrayList<A>(aList));
        System.out.println(immutableList.toString());//result is 99 as expected
        a.setA(50);
        System.out.println(immutable.toString());//result is 50 and I was expecting 99
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to do a deep copy of each object. See the [clonable interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html). And probably to wrap it in something that will prevent the changes.

Comment: You could hide the implementation behind an Interface that doesnt provide setters.

Comment: @rollback but if another class have an instance that is not hiden behind the interface, the object will still change

Comment: *How* immutable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably make `A` implement an interface (`I`) which exposes the necessary data (via getters) but **doesn't** expose any mutator methods.

Then, where I needed the immutable list/array, I'd use `I` rather than `A`.

This doesn't protect you from nefarious casts or reflection, but then, virtually nothing does.

Note that if you change an object that's in the list *not* via the list, that change will be visible via the list. So it's not true immutability:

```
A a = new A(1);
List<I> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(a);
System.out.println(list.get(0).getValue()); // 1
a.setValue(2);
System.out.println(list.get(0).getValue()); // 2
```

For **true** immutability, you'll have to clone the objects into (say) `ImmutableA` instances that expose no setters and maintain no backward link to their original object.